# c# insert DateTime in mysql with Parameters

Tags: c#, mysql

winforms c#. при добавлении значение dateTimePicker в базу данных mysql возникает ошибка. Не удалось привести тип объекта "ObjectCollection" к типу "System.IConvertible"." пробовал конвертировать по разному, но пока никаких результатов. может кто-нибудь поможет в этом разобраться . самое удивительное если запрос сделать +datetimepicker.Text + работает а через Parametrs ошибку выдает. ниже выложил код.

```
private void Addbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      //  DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //    string formatForMySql = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            string query = "insert into sta(name, satstype, year, prefix, size, freesize, internetsize, freesizeint, abonplata, dslam48, date) Values (@name, @satstype, @year, @prefix, @size, @freesize, @internetsize, @freesizeint, @abonplata, @dslam48, @date)";
         
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = AutoNumberedTable(dt);
        
           
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
          
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@satstype", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = comboBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = comboBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@prefix", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@size", MySqlDbType.Int32, 20).Value = textBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@freesize", MySqlDbType.Int32, 20).Value = textBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@internetsize", MySqlDbType.Int32, 20).Value = textBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@freesizeint", MySqlDbType.Int32, 20).Value = textBox6.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@abonplata", MySqlDbType.Int32, 20).Value = comboBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dslam48", MySqlDbType.Int32, 20).Value = comboBox4.Items;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            con.Open();
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Added!");
        }

        con.Close();

        spisok();
    
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@dslam48", MySqlDbType.Int32, 20).Value = comboBox4.SelectedIndex;`

Comment: спасибо , насчет dateTimePicker1 что скажете ?  именно с этим возникает ошибка

Comment: Нет, не с этим. Исключение у вас именно про Items.

Comment: дааа, спасибо !  все работает !

Comment: можете помочь разобраться еще с одной проблемой ?  в Combobox вывел таблицы баз данных . теперь хочу выбирать одну из таблиц и туда добавлять данные, проблема возникает в том что как сделать запрос правильным.

Comment: ` MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                if (comboBox1.Text == "sta60")                               { query = "insert into sta60(name, surname, phone, login, dslam, port, date, ip) Values (@name, @surname, @phone, @login, @dslam, @port, @date, @ip)";
                    ExecuteQuery(query); 
                    if (comboBox1.Text == "sta70") {
                        query = "insert into sta70(name, surname, phone, login, dslam, port, date, ip) Values (@name, @surname, @phone, @login, @dslam, @port, @date, @ip)";
                    ExecuteQuery(query); } `

Comment: Если есть новый вопрос, его можно задать отдельно.

Comment: хорошо, благодарю !